# How to hide and show buttons in a timer loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to hide and show a number of buttons at random which should run in a 30 sec timer.

How is a timer created in objective C?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)  class is what your looking for.